# Window_Closing event not triggering

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have Window A and Window B. Window B can be opened as a dialog box from Window A (so Window A will remain inactive/disabled as long as Window B is open). But as soon as *Window B closes* I need to trigger a re-query for a datagrid in *Window A*.

I tried creating a Window_Closing event but when I try to compile I get the error message "Window_Closing" is not a member of Window B.

Am I not placing my triggers and subs correctly?

Window A VB:

```
Public Sub Window_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CancelEventArgs)
    '
    ' Load/Refresh datagrid in Window A once Window B closes
    '
    Dim records = [LINQ2SQL QUERY]
    '
    ' Create the SQL Connection String
    '
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(Main_Connect)

        connection.Open()

        Try

            DataGrid.ItemsSource = records

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error: " & ex.Message)

        End Try

        connection.Close()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Window B XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="WindowB"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dashboard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dashboard" Height="475" Width="825" Closing="Window_Closing">
</Window>
```

Comment: You write "Window **A** VB" and "Window **B** XAML" - do you see the mismatch?

Comment: It is because I need the event to occur in Window A once Window B is closed.

Comment: That is however not the way it is supposed to be implemented. If you write `Closing="Window_Closing"` in XAML, the handler method must be declared in that XAML's code behind class. If you want to attach a handler to the Closing event of a different object, write something like `windowB.Closing += Window_Closing;` (or the equivalent VB code) where `windowB` is an instance of the WindowB class.